# Adding sections for font size and style to a pickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have made a font selector that displays all fonts inside the wheel.

I now need to add 2 extra sections to it for altering the font size and style (bold, italic, underlined).

Are style and size members of the UIFont class? And if so, how are they accessed?

Here is the code I'm using :

.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *fonts;


    NSMutableArray *fontNames;
    NSArray *fontSize;
    NSArray *fontStyle;

}


@property (strong, nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *fontPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fontLabel;

@end
```

the updated .m file. This gives me a section to pick a size, but it changes the font as well :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

#define MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE 13

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



     fontNames = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            [fontNames addObject:fontName];
        }
    }

    _fontPicker.hidden = YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if(component == 0)
    {
    return fontNames.count;
    }
    else if (component == 1){
        return MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE + 17;
    }


    return -1;

}



- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component
           reusingView:(UIView *)view {


  UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;
    if (component == 0) {

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 80, 32);
        pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        pickerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        pickerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fontNames objectAtIndex:row]];
        pickerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[fontNames objectAtIndex:row] size:15];
        return pickerLabel;

    } else if (component == 1) {
        sizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,80,32)];
         sizeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        sizeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        sizeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (row + MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE)];
           return sizeLabel;
    }

    return nil;




}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    _fontLabel.text = [fontNames objectAtIndex:row];
    _fontLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[fontNames objectAtIndex:row] size:MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE];

    if(component == 1)
    {
        _fontLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[fontNames objectAtIndex:row] size:row+MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE];
    }




}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(id)sender {

   _fontPicker.hidden = NO;



}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size is separate and not dependent upon the font.

Bold and italic are dependent upon the font and should already be covered by your handling of the font names.

Things like underline and strike through are presentation attributes so are not dependent upon the font (drawn explicitly or via attributed string).

---

To add font size:

Change `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` to `return 2;`

Change `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` to

```
if (component == 0) {
    // add the current code you have here
} else {
    // create a new label here
    pickerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (row + MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE)];
}
```

Add `#define MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE 13`

p.s. don't use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",` if you already have a string (you do), it's pointless and wasteful.

---

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _fontLabel.text = [fontNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    _fontLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontNames objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]
                                  size:MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE + [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
}
```

Comment: how would i add size and bold/italic to my picker wheel? i've only started using that controller yesterday so i'm a little green

Comment: if i just used font family names and then altered bold/italic, would that work?

Comment: Not all fonts have bold / italic so you would need to do some processing on the font names to decide if you should show the user the options...

Comment: could you add an example for adding the font size section to the picker view?

Comment: this does add an extra section, but it's empty

Comment: i can't seem to get them to work independently, will edit my question

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of `MINIMUM_ALLOWED_FONT_SIZE`. It is to limit the user so they can't choose a small font size that would be unreadable. In some places you use it correctly but not in others. Also, in `didSelectRow` you need to the the selected row for component 0 for the font and selected row for component 1 for the size. You can't use the row passed as a parameter...

Comment: If i use an if to determine between the components, it still does not work though

Comment: In `didSelectRow` don't use an `if`, just get the selected row for each component because you need to know the selected font and selected size whenever anything changes.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "get"?

Comment: Using the selectedRowInComponent: method

Comment: so i just return row inComponent 1 and 2 ?